# Where to find 'libodb-sqlite' package for 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, sqlite

I am a user of Ubuntu 14.04 and need to install the package libodb-sqlite. However, this is not yet available for my version of Ubuntu. I have seen if [for the later Ubuntu version 16.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libodb-sqlite-2.4). What shall I do?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu adopted the package and backported to the 16.04 "universe" but did not go back any further in time. The page you referred to also shows the dependencies the package has. Those dependencies need to be present in 14.04, too, for the package to build. The devil may be in the detail, but from here, not too much extra work seems to be required, except for the additional backport of the libodb-2.4 package.

It may be worthwhile to ask the maintainers for 16.04 to perform the backport for yet an additional release. You could certainly also perform the backport yourself. If you professionally depend on a smooth operation of 14.04, not a completely uncommon scenario, you should consider to find some professionals that you would pay to provide this and other kind of support ... or to plan with you a transition to later versions of Ubuntu.